# new article is not getting submitted in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

```
<?php
class Admin extends MY_Controller
    {
        public function dashboard()
            {
                /*
                if(! $this->session->userdata('user_id')) // This condition is check condition which will show dashboard only if person is logged in else will redirect to login page.
                    return redirect('login');
                */

                $this->load->model('articlesmodel','articles');  // This "articles" is the secondary name which we have given here and will be refering to.
                $articles = $this->articles->articles_list();   // If we have given the secondary name then we need to use that seconary name here too.
                // In above line, we will get the titles/title which will get stored in $articles.


                $this->load->view('admin/dashboard.php',['articles'=>$articles]); // we are passing the received articles in here.
                // The above 'articles' will be received by "dashboard.php" in the form of "$articles".
            }


            public function add_article()
            {
                $this->load->helper('form');
                $this->load->view('admin/add_article.php');
            }


            public function store_article()
            {
                // Previously we use to form validate from the same file. But, now we have set the rules and all in config's form_validation file.
                // We just need to pass the rule in the run like below.
                $this->load->library('form_validation');
                if($this->form_validation->run('add_articles_rules'))
                {
                    // If we pass the parameter inside post then we will get that value only else it will give all the inputs in the array. 
                    $post = $this->input->post();
                    unset($post['submit']); // this is to remove submit value received in $post array else it will give error.

                    $this->load->model('articlesmodel','articles');
                    if($this->articles->add_article($post))
                    {
                        echo "Insert sucessful";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        echo "Insert uncessful";
                    }
                }

                else
                {
                    return redirect('admin/add_article');
                }
            }


            public function edit_article()
            {

            }

            public function delete_article()
            {

            }

            public function __construct()
                {
                    parent::__construct();
                    if(! $this->session->userdata('user_id'))
                        return redirect('login');
                }
                // Above constructor can be placed in MY_Controller but then we need to undo the "login extends My_Controller" or make it as 
                // "login extends CI_Controller" as in this "admin" file we can have more methods.
    }           
?>
```

Comment: I am working with codeigniter where i have a page to submit the new article but it is not getting submitted. I don't know what is the issue. I have seen the code again and again many times though.

Sorry for poor code paste, stackoverflow is confusing for me.
Besides, link for ral code is here,     
http://paste.ofcode.org/RgwMUrPN64VSaZXddAh2kS

Comment: The store article work is being done by the articles model.  Can you post the code for that so we can see what's happening?

Comment: Its the "articlesmodel" comtroller



<?php
 class Articlesmodel extends CI_Model
 {
  public function articles_list()
  {
   $user_id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');  // session variables are available globaly.

    $query = $this->db
        ->select('title')
        ->from('articles')
        ->where('user_id', $user_id)
        ->get();
   return $query->result();     
  }


  public function add_article($array)
  {
   return $this->db->insert('articles', $array);
  }
 }

?>

Comment: its link is here


http://paste.ofcode.org/gHVWaE79Bh3dt2MEkphMRk

Comment: Based on that, my initial suggestion would be to load the database in the model.  It doesn't appear to be loaded by your application.  You'll need `$this->load->database()`

Comment: its already autoloaded :D

Comment: other thing is when i am pressing the submit button without entering anything for article, it is not even throwing error.

Comment: Does your post array have all of the required information for the article table, and are there more fields being posted than the table requires?  If you `var_dump($post)` do the array keys match the column names in the database table?

Comment: i simply just did validation and post the received arrays and it come out to be that it got nothing, its blank.

Comment: can you suggest something ?